# Wiremock proxy forwarding different header's user-agent

Tags: java, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I'm using Wiremock to proxy my network from a real device. My current setup is just to forward all network to our BE service.
Our service expect a custom user-agent, which is whitelisting the calls, otherwise it gets recognised as bot and blocks all incoming calls.

I'm starting a Wiremock server as standalone with the following command:

```
java -jar wiremock-standalone-3.4.1.jar --port 9999 --enable-browser-proxying --trust-all-proxy-targets
```

When I run a test on my device, I can see network being recorded in the following URL:

```
http://localhost:9999/__admin/requests
```

All network calls recorded in the logs have a custom user-agent, exactly the same as it was sent from the client. Though, the network calls get rejected with the 403 error code. I checked on our BE and the received user-agent to our BE is **apache-httpClient/5.3.1 (Java/17.0.9)**, which is the reason for our BE to block the reuqest.

I assume the user-agent is rewritten by the Wiremock before is forwarded. So, my question is, how can I avoid this to happening? I want the value of the user-agent to remain the same as it was sent by the client (mobile device).